# The SKScene recognizes the high score of the GameScene

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sprite-kit

I want that my `SKScene` (`MedalScene`) recognizes the high score of the `GameScene` because if the high score is for example "20" then it will appear a medal. How I can do that?

My code in the GameScene for the high score:

```
NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[ud setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_score] forKey:SCORE_OVER];

int scoreString=[[ud objectForKey:BEST_SCORE] intValue];
if(scoreString < _score){
    [ud setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_score] forKey:BEST_SCORE];
    scoreString = _score;
```

And this is the currently code of my `MedalScene` for the medals:

```
if(scoreString >= 20){
    SKSpriteNode *medal1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"medal_1"];
    medal1.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX( self.frame )*1/4 + 8, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 21);
    [self addChild:medal1];
}
```

---

My GameScene shows the GameOver with the score as well as the high score. And this are the codes:

```
-(void)showGameOver{

NSUserDefaults *hud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[hud setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_score] forKey:SCORE_OVER];

int scoreString = [[hud objectForKey:BEST_SCORE] intValue];
if(scoreString < _score){
    [hud setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_score] forKey:BEST_SCORE];
    scoreString = _score;

SKLabelNode *lbOver = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Walibi0615"];
lbOver.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame)*3/4, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+33);
lbOver.zPosition = 1;
lbOver.fontSize = 20;
lbOver.fontColor = [UIColor blackColor];
lbOver.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _score];
[_gameOver addChild:lbOver];

SKLabelNode *lbMaxOver = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Walibi0615"];
lbMaxOver.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame)*3/4, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)-14);
lbMaxOver.zPosition = 1;
lbMaxOver.fontSize = 20;
lbMaxOver.fontColor = [UIColor blackColor];
lbMaxOver.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", scoreString];
[_gameOver addChild:lbMaxOver]; }
```

I have created a second scene (MedalScene) and this scene should recognize the scoreString of the GameScene because if for example, the high score is equal to 20 then it will appear a medal in this scene.

And this is the currently code for the medal (MedalScene):

```
if(scoreString >= 20){
SKSpriteNode *medal1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"medal_1"];
medal1.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX( self.frame )*1/4 + 8, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 21);
[self addChild:medal1]; }
```

I hope now it is clear what I mean. Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should synchronize your userdefaults after you set them.

```
[ud synchronize];
```

I'd use real integers inside your userdefaults too though (i.s.o. hand-converting to strings), so something like

```
NSInteger score = [ud integerForKey:BEST_SCORE];
if (_score > score)  {
    [ud setInteger:_score forKey:BEST_SCORE];
    [ud synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. If I replace the GameScene code with your code, the high score will disappear in the GameScene. So I want just a link to my MedalScene.

Comment: @StefanoVuottoCésar if you synchronize your userdefaults and they still don't show up in the other scene something else is wrong. To be honest it's rather hard to grasp what your exact problem is, your question doesn't make much sense and you post very little code. Try to explain your problem a bit clearer and/or post some more code.

Comment: @StefanoVuottoCésar after reading your edited question, it appears you do indeed need to add a synchronize call after changing your userdefaults, and you should use integers if you want to compare them to '20' (comparing a string to 20 as integer makes no sense).

Comment: I chanched a little bit your code and now it works! Thank you for your help Pieter!